# shared service is unable to pass data to next component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have created two components and one shared service, i want pass data from one component to another, but i am getting empty object
bellow is 1st component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from './../shared.service';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';



    @Component({
      selector: 'app-cone',
      templateUrl: './cone.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./cone.component.css'],
      providers: [SharedService]
    })
    export class ConeComponent implements OnInit {
    req = <any>{};
      constructor(public service:SharedService,private router:Router) { }
       send(){
        this.req.fname= "ketan";
        this.req.lname= "pradhan";
        this.service.saveData(this.req); 
        console.log('str');
        this.router.navigate(['/apps/ctwo']);
      }

      ngOnInit() {

      }

    }
```

Bellow is the 2nd component where i need to pass the data from 1st comonent, i am getting empty object is this.myName

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from './../shared.service';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ctwo',
  templateUrl: './ctwo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ctwo.component.css'],
  providers: [SharedService]
})
export class CtwoComponent implements OnInit {
myName= <any>{};

  constructor(public service:SharedService,private router:Router) {
    this.myName=this.service.getData();
        console.log(this.myName);
   }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Bellow is shared service which is for communicating between 2 components

import {Component, Injectable,Input,Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'

// Name Service
export interface myData {
   name:string,
   lname:string
}

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  sharingData: myData=<any>{};
  saveData(str){
    console.log('save data function called' + str.fname);
    console.log(this.sharingData);
    this.sharingData = str; 
    // this.sharingData.lname=str.lname; 
    console.log(this.sharingData)
  }
  getData()
  {
    console.log('get data function called');
    return this.sharingData;
  }
}
```

Comment: declare the service on module level (NgModule) providers array. Now you have it in providers array in both components, which means you have separate instances of the service. So basically it's not at all a shared service :)

Comment: If you want to share the service in these two components only, then you have to declare it in the `providers` array of the parent of these components and then it will be shared by these two only

Comment: it's best register the service in the @NgModule.providers, register a provider with a component you limit the scope of a service instance to that component and its component tree. See that https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#should-i-add-other-providers-to-a-module-or-a-component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are setting `providers` arrays at component level, it means that you have **two** separate instances of the service in this case.

You need to declare the service in your `NgModule` `providers` array instead, then the two components (and any other components in that module) will have the same instance of the service.

So remove the `providers` arrays in your components, and instead add the service to providers array in your `NgModule`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ctwo',
  templateUrl: './ctwo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ctwo.component.css'],
  // providers: [SharedService] // remove these!
})
```

and instead....

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ ... ],
  declarations: [ .. ],
  bootstrap: [ ... ],
  providers: [ SharedService ] // here!
})
```

Comment: can anyone guide me how to implement datepicker in angular 4

Comment: @KetanPradhan Unfortunately I'm not familiar with that, I suggest you open a new question with that so that you can get some help from people who do know about it :)